# Cargar desde un DataGridView diferentes formularios con los mismos campos pero diferentes características

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo diferentes formularios con los mismos campos pero con diferentes características .

Quiero cargar desde un DataGridView el formulario correspondiente dependiendo de los valores de txtTransporte y txtTipo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    private void dgvConsultas_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var transporte = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        var tipo = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        if (transporte == "A" && tipo == "E")
        {
            frmCotizacionesAE form = new frmCotizacionesAE();
        }

        if (transporte == "A" && tipo == "I")
        {
            frmCotizacionesAI form = new frmCotizacionesAI();
        }

        form.lblReferencia.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        form.lblEstado.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        form.lblAnno.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        form.lblTransporte.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        form.lblTipo.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        form.txtCliente.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        form.txtContacto.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    // --- más campos ---
        form.txtSeguroV.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[44].Value.ToString();
        form.txtSeguroC.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[45].Value.ToString();
        form.txtValidez.Text = dgvConsultas.CurrentRow.Cells[46].Value.ToString();

        form.Show();
    }
```

Da error al usar "form" para ambos formularios. Tengo 11 formularios similares (con 47 campos cada uno) y no quisiera repetir el código usando: form, form1, form2, etc. por cada formulario.

Agradeceré su amable ayuda.

Muchas gracias y saludos.

Ricardo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te da?

Comment: me temo que para que le funcione el codigo que va despues de los 'if' va a tener que meterlo dentro de cada uno y duplicarlo si quiere que le funcione, si el codigo es muy extenso debe usar otros caminos

Comment: En todos los form. da el error: "The name 'form' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Estimado Luis Carlos, alguna idea de como hacerlo sin duplicar código? Gracias.

Comment: Y si crear los objetos en tiempo de ejecucion para cada formulario? has pensado de esa manera?

Answer (score 1):

`"The name 'form' does not exist in the current context"` este error puede ser  porque no existen todos los casos dentro de tus if para crear la instancia "form"

Podrías intanciar al formulario desde su nombre: 
Por ejemplo llamar a un formCotizacionesAE:

```
 private void dgvConsultas_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    var transporte = "A" 
    var tipo = "E"

    Form frm = GetForm("formCotizaciones"+transporte+tipo);
                if (frm!=null)
                { 
                    //campos
                    frm.Show();
                }
}
     public Form GetForm(string formName)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(formName)) return null;
                System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

                foreach (Type ty in asm.GetTypes())
                {
                   if(ty.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == formName.ToUpperInvariant())
                    {
                        formName = ty.Namespace +"." + ty.Name;
                    }
                }

                 Object o = asm.CreateInstance(formName);
                 return o as Form;

            }
```

-Algo parecido podras intentar con los lbl,seguire investigando sobre el tema para dar una respuesta completa